# No route matches scoped resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-routing

1. `rails new example`
2. `rails g scaffold widget`
3. `rake db:migrate`
4. Edit routes.rb as follows: `scope ":year" do resources :widgets end`
5. `curl http://0.0.0.0:3000/2011/widgets` is successful
6. `echo "Widget.new.save" | rails c`
7. `curl http://0.0.0.0:3000/2011/widgets/1` is successful
8. But now `curl http://0.0.0.0:3000/2011/widgets` fails with the following error:

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"widgets", :year=>#<Widget id: 1` .. etc.

Why does it think the action is "show"?  Why does it think the year is a widget instance?  Very strange.  I get the same result in rails 3.0.9 and 3.1.0.rc6.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
resources :widgets
```

(with S in the end)

UPD: in index.html.erb instead of

```
link_to widget
```

use smth like

```
link_to widget_path(widget, :year => 2011)
```

or

```
link_to widget_path(2011, widget)
```

Comment: I did have `resources :widgets` (that was a typo in my question), but I was missing the year in the calls to widget_path().  I should have looked more closely at the stack trace.   It's kind of a misleading error message (no route matches) but now I see what was going on.  Thanks.

Comment: Instead of specifying the year in each invocation of `widget_path()`, I found it much easier to add `def default_url_options(options={})
    { :year => @year }
  end` to my `ApplicationController`.  I won't mention how many hours I wasted before I discovered default_url_options :-)